# jQuery datetimepicker - Date formatting not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using jQuery datetimepicker plugin from [this](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) site.

I would like to format the date in format `DD.MM.YYYY` but in spite of setting below, when I pick the value from calendar it's still formatted as *YYYY/MM/DD*:

```
jQuery('#inputdHACC_DST').datetimepicker(
{
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
});
```

Is it possible to format date value like *DD/MM/YYYY* and override the default?

Comment: Replace dateFormat with format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dateFormat` to `format`

```
jQuery('#inputdHACC_DST').datetimepicker(
{
    format: 'd.m.Y H:i'
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work - 1717-1111-1616    - this come out for 17.11.2016. Which version you use? Main is 2.4.5

Comment: What about time? I need date and time

Comment: A sample output for **`d.m.Y`** format is *24.11.2016*

Comment: On my version is 24.11.16

Comment: If u can, put your code on jsfiddle and share me the link